# What is the expected amount of time until the chain is in state 4?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning, markov-chains

> Consider the continuous-time markov chain with state space {1,2,3,4}
>   and infinitesimal generator 
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix}-2&1&1&0\\0&-1&1&0\\1&1&-3&1\\0&0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> a)Find the equilibrium distribution $\pi$
>
> b)Suppose the chain starts in state 1. What the expected amount of
>   time until it changes states for the first time?
>
> c)Again assume the chain starts in state 1. What is the expected
>   amount of time until the chain is in state 4?

a)I solve the system $$\pi A=0$$ with the condition $$\pi(1)+\pi(2)+\pi(3)+\pi(4)=1$$ and get $$\pi=(\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{2}{8},\frac{2}{8})$$

b)If we start at state $1$ we have that $$a(1,2)=1$$ $$a(1,3)=1$$ $$a(1,4)=0$$
so the change rate is $\sum_j a(1,j)=2 \forall i\neq j$ then the amount of time is $$\frac{1}{\sum_j a(1,j)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

c)Here I am lost, the idea presented in the book involves calculating the inverse matrix of $A$ without the column and row of state $4$

Comment: For part (a) you should be trying to solve $A\pi=\pi$

Comment: Why? That would be not only to Markov chain in discrete time?

Comment: Sorry thinking discretely. Ignore me.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain#Expected_hitting_times and it becomes clear why you need to invert $-A_{-(4,4)}$ and multiply by a column of three $1$'s.

Comment: Starting in state $i\ne 4$ and consider transitions in the following $\delta t$. Compute new expected hitting time, add $\delta t$ and equate to the hitting time from the state you started in.

Comment: To solve c), the canonical approach is to consider the whole family $(t_x)$ where $t_x$ is the expected amount of time until the chain is in state $4$ starting from state $x\ne4$. Then $$t_1=\tfrac12+\tfrac12t_2+\tfrac12t_3\quad t_2=1+t_3\quad t_3=\tfrac13+\tfrac13t_1+\tfrac13t_2+\tfrac13t_4\quad t_4=0.$$ Solving this affine system yields $$t_1=4.$$